# is to possible to add ssis project to visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dts, ssis

our project has two parts.. the SSIS packages that are executed by sql jobs and the mainstream mvc3 web-application. We are at the point of creating the deployable units. Wondering if theres anyway to add/include the SSIS project into the Visual Studio solution so that one solution file opens up the project as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 doesn't support SSIS projects yet. So, you can't add SSIS project to a VS 2010 solution. If you are using VS 2008 then you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can that. Open any one of your project in VS, right click on solution->Add->Existing Project-> point to your second application.